# Remove GET parameters from file names in directory

Tags: filenames

I need to remove the part starting with `?` from a bunch of files with names like `image.jpg?foo=bar&bar=foo`. Would someone please show me how it's done?

These commands aren't working for some reason:

```
rename "\?." "" *
rename 's/(.*)\.jpg\?.*/$1\.jpg/' *
```

Comment: I am not familar with the rename utility. But `find . -name \?* -ls` does select all the files starting with a question mark.  You could replace the -ls with a mv and basename.

Comment: Debian and Red Hat each have a `rename` command. But they are very different. You did not mention which `rename` command you are using, and the arguments you used doesn't look like they would be appropriate for either.

Comment: @kasperd Sorry, didn't think the OS would matter. Mine is CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple:

We are working in a for loop on every file, whose name contains a '`?`'.

This for loop calls an `mv` (== rename) command with all of these files, *plus* these filenames without their part after that '`?`'.

The exact command is the following:

```
for i in *\?*;do mv -vf "${i}" "${i%%\?*}";done
```

Which seems maybe a little bit cryptic, is the `"${i%%\?*}"`. That means: "the variable named 'i', removed from its tail everything after a '`?`'.

There is also a little bit cryptic thing, that is the part `*\?*`. It means every file in the current directory, whose name contains a '`?`'. This is a pattern, just as in (win)do(w)s, the only difference is that the '`?`' means by default every character. The backslash ('`\`') is used to remove this special meaning from that.